# How to Browse files from folder without open it

Tags: c#, wpf, dollar-sign

I work with this code to open folder and browse files from it, but i need to get this files without open folder,when I run my program automatically load this files, I try to use `GetFiles()` but didn't work with me when apply the filter for files i want to select 
this is my code

```
OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();             
dlg.InitialDirectory = @"C:\Users\ahmed\Desktop\samples";
dlg.Filter = "Gestures (*.xml)|*.xml";
dlg.Title = "Load Gestures";
dlg.RestoreDirectory = false;
dlg.Multiselect = true;

if (dlg.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dlg.FileNames.Length; i++)
    {
        string name = dlg.FileNames[i];
        _rec.LoadGesture(name);
    }
    ReloadViewForm();
}
```

Comment: did you try Directory.GetFiles() ?

Comment: Does the user need to select a folder or files in a folder?

Comment: @RvdK No, load this files only to do some process

Comment: @Ahmed Elzeiny Since you edited the question, you can use Linq like these Directory.GetFiles().ToList<String>().Select(fname=>fname.contains(".xml")).ToList()

Comment: @kanchirk how i get the loaded files name ?

Comment: @AhmedElzeiny do you mean the current fileName ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It returns the names of files (including their paths) in the specified directory.

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\");

foreach (var file in files)
{
    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
    Console.WriteLine(fileInfo.Name);
}
```

Comment: I try it but can't get files name